# Windows based portable PPTP Client separate from built-in OS client

Tags: vpn, portable, pptp

Is there any Windows based portable pptp client separate from built-in OS client that I can put on my jump drive for use in a lock-down PC User/Guest account in XP or Vista?

I would like to use my Personal-VPN connection, which uses OpenVPN protocol, in the public library.  Their PCs are locked down so I can't setup the Windows PPTP client within the OS to establish a point-to-point VPN connection.  The library will let me use any USB dongle.  Thanks.

Comment: "The library will let me use any USB dongle.", then bring you usb key with the OS of your choice on it !

Answer (score 1):

First, PPTP clients cannot be used for OpenVPN:

> ...my Personal-VPN connection, which uses OpenVPN protocol, ...

and

> ...I can't setup the Windows PPTP client...

---

Second, to use a VPN connection, you usually need to tell the OS where to route packets, which cannot be done without at least Administrator privileges. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

...my Personal-VPN connection, which uses OpenVPN protocol, ...

I'm using Witopia VPN service, and they do use the OpenVPN protocol with a handy PPTP VPN for those who don't want to install any thing on their PC or laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up [Adito](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/) - now, it's been three years since the last update (and also three years since they've intended to start renaming it "OpenVPN ALS") but still works great.

Adito is a web-based SSL VPN; it works through the browser and uses browser Java applets to create port-by-port tunnels.  Traffic looks like SSL HTTP.  It has a lot of other features too, like comprehensive access control and a file manager.

I successfully used this to RDP into my home computer from my restricted school environment.  I continue to use it a lot to RDP into my home computer from work :P.